# Alternative to PreInit for UserControl When Dynamically Adding Controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, user-controls

I am trying to implement the solution found in the following article: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/aspnet-ajax/how-to-dynamically-add-controls-to-a-web-page

Instead of adding the code to a web form (like the demo does), I am trying to implement the article's code in a User Control. Since this is a User Control, there is no PreInit. What would be the appropriate event to add this to?

Comment: isn't there an OnInit()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See OnInit() event for asp.net usercontrols.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol.oninit(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Have you tried this? When I add control in OnInit event, it throws exception "The control collection cannot be modified during DataBind, Init, Load, PreRender or Unload phases."